# SVG stroke-linecap doesn't work for circles in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, svg

I've got a problem with svg stroke-linecap attribute. I've got circular progress bar in AngularJS and I would like to set the outer circle (blue one) to have a rounded "ends". Look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gxwngagw/).

```
<svg ... height="130" width="130">
<!-- ngIf: background -->
<circle ... 
    ng-if="background" 
    fill="#fff" 
    class="ng-scope" 
    stroke-width="13" 
    stroke="#cc3399" 
    r="57.5" 
    cy="65" 
    cx="65" 
    stroke-linecap="round" 
/>
<!-- end ngIf: background -->
<circle ... 
    fill="none" 
    stroke-dashoffset="36.12831551628261" 
    stroke-dasharray="361.28315516282623" 
    stroke-width="13" 
    stroke="#432db3" 
    stroke-linecap="round" 
    r="57.5" 
    cy="65" 
    cx="65" 
    transform="rotate(-89.9, 65, 65)"
/>
</svg>
```

How can i do that?

Comment: It does have rounded ends on Chrome.

Comment: But not in Mozilla. Interesting.

Comment: Yes, I'm developing the website in Firefox and there are no rounded ends :(

Comment: Same issue as with the baseline property support in svg and some other svg properties, svg support in firefox is worse then ie/edge, which is kinda sad....

Comment: @seahorsepip what are you talking about ? firefox, as other browsers do support baseline properties. You probably don't know how to use it. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/alignment-baseline, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/baseline-shift). As of today, we could say that there are some gaps in FF support (maybe you were talking about `letter-spacing` which is indeed not supported). but from my experience, FF has the best svg support across web-browsers.

Comment: Ohh my bad I meant letter spacing, I was confused and sayed baseline since I was answering a SO question related to svg baseline a short time ago .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been [fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1242147) from Firefox 45 onwards.